# Code::Blocks debugging issue

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I'm debugging my programs using Code::Blocks and I'm facing following issue: I do not see vector's members in Watches.
Why is this happening? How do I deal with it?[image]

Comment: What's your actual problem? Presumably, being able to see members of std::vector are a means to an end. Incidently, std::vector doesn't have any public data - only public functions.

Comment: @enhzflep, I'd like to keep track on vector's members as it's possible in Visual Studio debugging mode

Comment: No can do with C::B and GDB. Just use `printf`/`cout`. In your code, it seems that you're possible trying to index beyond the bounds of the vector. Dont forget that vector.size() returns the number of elements, the last one is accessed with vector[vector.size()-1]. Since you're accessing both `[i]` and `[i+1]`, you need to bail if your i ever reaches `vector.size() - 2` (I dont know what `count` holds, it may be something else entirely) - OffTopic: thanks for alerting me that GDB _is_ functional in C::B under windows. Haven't used GDB in over 15 years. :)

Comment: This is definitely possible with Code Blocks and gdb.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install python pretty printers on the gdb version you are using to be able to display the content of vectors correctly, see this [link](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Pretty_Printers).